# Using azure custom activity to run c# executable which converts DBF file into CSV

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, dbf, custom-activity

Is there any way to query a dbf file stored in azure blob storage and then put the results into a data table? So far I was downloading the dbf file locally and then I was using OleDb connection to query the dbf file and load the results into a data table. Now I am moving my executable into Azure Data Factory as a custom activity and therefore there is no local path to download the dbf file. Is there any other way to query a dbf file stored in azure blob storage without having to download it? My executable is written in c#. Can you point me to the right direction?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Azure Data Lake Gen2 rather than Azure Storage, you can query your files using USQL. (PS: dbf is not a valid format in this case)

Your executable can be replaced by an Azure Function, which can be an activity in your Azure Data Factory pipeline:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#:~:text=%20Azure%20Function%20activity%20in%20Azure%20Data%20Factory,Activity%20supports%20routing.%20For%20example%2C%20if...%20More%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20Function%20activity%20in%20Azure%20Data%20Factory,Activity%20supports%20routing.%20For%20example%2C%20if...%20More%20)

Comment: I am afraid that I can't replace my executable because there are some other stuff done there as well. However, If I use Azure Data Lake Gen2 will I be able to query a dbf file stored there using c#? Is it possible to give me an example?

Comment: No, you'll need to store the content of your dbf files in your data lake.